# How to show text on dock icons, Android 5.1.1?

Tags: dock

How to show text on dock icons, Android 5.1.1?

Android 5.1.1

CyanogenMod:
12.1-20151230-NIGHTLY-maserati

Searched all over and can't find a solution:

https://www.google.com/search?q=(text+OR+lost)+android+(bottom+row+OR+Dock)+home+screen+icons

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for has nothing to do with Android version or ROM's build running on the device. Labels for dock icons is a feature of the launcher app you're using. Every ROM has one launcher at least. CM comes with Trebuchet. I couldn't find support of labels for dock icons in that launcher under the latest snapshot (YOG7DAO1K6) for *bacon*. I also tried with [Xposed GEL Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.theknut.xposedgelsettings) with no success.

If you want that feature badly, consider changing your launcher app.

I'm aware of the following launchers having that have said feature:

- Slim Launcher of SlimLP (SlimROM) -- Feature accessible from Settings → Dock. Uncheck "Hide icon labels" there.

  I have SlimLP installed as a secondary ROM so it was easy for me to obtain the apk of Slim Launcher.

  <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

  [image: IMG:]
- [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) -- Feature accessible from Nova Settings → Dock → Icon layout → Label.

  [image: IMG:]

Comment: Thank you, Firelord!  This is an excellent response!  I had no idea that a "launcher" was involved.  Now I know.  Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply long press somewhere on the home screen. It opens a screen to edit the home screen which shows wallpapers, widgets, settings, apps. Click on the 3 dots (the one that looks like a triangle when connected). Go to home screen settings or drawer settings(depending upon your need). Then change icon labels from hide to show.